# Cannot update Mac Os on VM workstation

Tags: macos, virtual-machine

Someone, tell me how to overcome the error with such symptoms:
Windows 10, Mac OS High Sierra is installed on the VMware Workstation virtual machine.

There is one snapshot (I understand this is a recovery point).

There was a need to update the Mac OS High Sierra, but when updating, at the same place (when it is written that there is 41 minutes left) a dialog box pops up with the following text:

The operation on file "**D: \ macOS High Sierra \ macOS High Sierra.vmdk"** failed.

If the file resides on the remote file system, make sure that the network connection. If the file resides on removable media, reattach the media.

Select Retry to attempt the operation again.

Select Cancel to end this session.

Select Continue to forward the error to the guest operating system.

None of the options lead to success.

After trying to install updates, the system can not start more (it starts with updates and a vicious circle turns out). We have to roll back to the snapshot. And everything works fine. But further, when you try to download and install updates, the above situation arises again.

It's unclear what the problem is. The disk is damaged (but how does it get to roll back to the recovery point), or maybe there is not enough rights (how to register them) or something else?

Googling the problem did not help.